# Можно ли запустить JavaFx на стандартной JRE1.6?

Tags: java, javafx

Во время запуска вываливает:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/runtime/FXObject`

Comment: а почему нет?

Comment: @Viacheslav, добавил что у меня происходит при попытке

Comment: не сталкивался, но если вы считаете что ошибка в версии, то >Для JavaFX 1.2 и выше рекомендуется использовать Java SE 6 Update 10 и выше.

Comment: [JavaFX – Hands On][1]


  [1]: http://blog.jayway.com/2009/05/01/javafx-hands-on/

Comment: @Gorets, вы хотите сказать, что fx не запуститься в обычной java? А вот это:
[Using JavaFX 2.0 inside Swing applications][1]


  [1]: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ixmal/archive/2011/06/02/using-javafx-20-inside-swing-applications

Answer (score 1):

Можно в версии 2.0 как например тут: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ixmal/archive/2011/06/02/using-javafx-20-inside-swing-applications